# abstract classes, send implementation to a method

Tags: java, abstract

I have 2 classes as follows.

```
public absract class myAbstracClass{

//various methods and stuff.

}

public class myImplmentationOfAbstractClass extends myAbstractClass {

//just implments a call to the abstract class in the constructor.
//no extrac functionality is added in this instance.
}
```

In a third class I have a method

```
public class someFunctionality{//

//default constructor

public static void myMethod(myAbstractClass abc)
//do stuff with abc

}
```

In my code I then call this method

```
public class doWork{

    public static void main(){

    //create my implmented class
    myImplmentationOfAbstractClass myABC = new myImplmentationOfAbstractClass();

    //send this class to my function

    someFunctionality.myMethod(myABC);//this causes an NPE

    }

    }
```

I'm obviously missing something, and I'm not finding it on google.

For now I've changed my method to accept a myImplementationOfAbstractClass object. But this seems bad new as I expect to need to use the abstract class again, and extnd it for specific instances.

Am I going about this incorrectly, or can I not send a subclass of a superclass to a method expecting a copy of the superclass?

thanks in advance.

David.

edit:

I just want to say thanks to everyone who has taken the time to answer. You are all correct. The problem was elsewhere.

It turns out that within my function I was declaring another 'temp object' and I was declaring its members in a bad order... took a while to find that one!

Once again, thanks guys, The process of writing the question was as helpfull as the responses. We all got to the same conclusion, at about the sime time (me I realised it just as you where posting the response I guess).

Comment: Does the same code after changing the myMethod parameter to subclass? That would be strange!

Comment: What you describe seems impossible so there must be something else. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error in your method `myMethod`.
this code

```
myImplmentationOfAbstractClass myABC = new myImplmentationOfAbstractClass();
someFunctionality.myMethod(myABC);//this causes an NPE
```

cannt' throw NPE

Comment: Indeed it was deep inside a sub method that was part of the myMethod that was throwing out the NPE. It got caught on this line by accident. I just couldn't find anything 'sensible' in the stact trace initially because the NPE was happening 3 or 4 calls further in! (is this bad design?)

Answer (score 1):

> There is nothing wrong with the code snippet youve provided, the cause of null pointer exception is something else ... may be if you check the stack trace or if you can identify exactly which line is causing the issue, it will better help identifying the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First guess: Your problem is somewhere else: There is nothing wrong with providing an implementation as an argument, if the argument type is supposed to be a superclass or interface of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I've just realised that the class that had the function in it wasn't building correctly, so the NPE was due to the method it was due to my stupidity in not setting a variable to null prior to using it!

So +1 to all those who bothered to answer. I realised this just as you guys where writing.